# Erlang Crypto Verify for Android Purchase Data

Tags: cryptography, erlang, google-play

I am using the crypto:verify which checks the google play purchase information, to be an "bad argument exception". I want you to know how.

```
OrderData = <<"{\"orderId\":\"12999763169054705758.1323507343902706\",\"packageName\":\"...\",\"productId\":\"item1\",\"purchaseTime\":1385090498734,\"purchaseState\":0,\"developerPayload\":\"DEVELOPER_PAYMENT\",\"purchaseToken\":\"...\"}">>),
PublicKeyString = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAs4WYUM+LiABp/fp5YHngKjpCslKyhMIosBND3nbgFyrt2bv7Bd8nVl80kOWHPWR8HLUH5u+r8MP9KF7klG8OiWk1GROgs3pHB5BNl2TdOIT6rtnUJXslFqlnGh5IlpShJVUIrO2ADbXmwsN3AviZBw0ZjctfjK5t1UOvptSDGolBl5UtoVZ/TNjpa6QtMPtccGRDNmXAWFrEhTMDLdH+EPeapAmxi/rY0RBDMdobj1UtQdFA+iGlp6adbkjW7xFGWxyjS+dKFbn/jULxILfLVQ3XpGZXQMGW3FvyAvuZBM1ZWHrM4t0aQZGSHsvCste7hMe97lozsuXsb8JdfRjdO..."),
DataSignature = <<"MxauTspbl/1pB8836+sgM8Jw//auJ2VzIhV4JlxAHNJQ2klA20F8m2d/+60Px0MPCPhU478ezn4Jsy168RKjz+dTUjjwgN118uTO8aKjQ8DVwVNVR9FzljFSou2V9hY4TitzEyhl6Iy5B7GqReRsbd4b1YajLkuwRKIt4vSBlamqjVBBbgqGuq8ppRPp15wruRRMJdVHlZXXXmiDw1pd+nr7z9CXVZ0nAyivy9Tq8W1clKUmtHdQt3NtOR4kXiFfiu6+IOAedn1uwV2akfBTd5UD0/PbJeXy8sNWF/2yjzCGbn9HZJqGBG2R9HSehcolvhGI7mAwam8nt7ljkO0Gww==">>),

SizedBinary = fun(Binary) -> <<(size(Binary)):32/integer,  Binary/binary>> end,
Hash = crypto:hash(sha, OrderData),

PublicKey =  base64:decode(PublicKeyString), %% (is valid ???)
Signature1 = base64:decode(DataSignature),   %% (is valid ???)
crypto:rsa_verify(SizedBinary(Hash), Signature1, PublicKey).

** exception error: bad argument
     in function  crypto:rsa_verify_nif/4
```

Comment: The Signature1 parameter to `rsa_verify` should be a SizedBinary as well.

Comment: `PubKeyLen = 65537, PublicKey =  [ <<PubKeyLen:32/integer-big>>, ?PublicKeyModulus ], crypto:verify(rsa , sha, ?OrderData, Signature, PublicKey). ok`

Answer (score 2):

Validated Code.

```
{ok, PemBin} = file:read_file("test.pem"),
[RSAEntry] = public_key:pem_decode(PemBin),
{_KeyType, Modulus, Exponent} = public_key:pem_entry_decode(RSAEntry),
RSAPubKey = [Exponent, Modulus],
Signature = base64:decode(?DataSignature),  
crypto:verify(rsa, sha, ?OrderData, Signature, RSAPubKey).
> ok.
```

Comment: For those who are using a public key copied from your Android app, replace the first line with 
PemBin = <<"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n", PublicKeyString, "\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----">>,

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you need to decode with base64 codec? Because according to the documentation:

```
 rsa_verify(DataOrDigest, Signature, Key) -> Verified
 rsa_verify(DigestType, DataOrDigest, Signature, Key) -> Verified 

 Types:

 Verified = boolean()
 DataOrDigest = Data | {digest|Digest}
 Data, Signature = Mpint
 Digest = binary()
 Key = [E, N]
 E, N = Mpint
 Where E is the public exponent and N is public modulus.
 DigestType = md5 | sha | sha224 | sha256 | sha384 | sha512
 The default DigestType is sha.
 Mpint = binary()
 Verifies that a digest matches the RSA signature using the signer's public key Key. The      digest is either calculated as a DigestType digest of Data or a precalculated binary Digest.

 May throw exception notsup in case the chosen DigestType is not supported by the underlying OpenSSL implementation.
```

AFAIK, [verify/5](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/crypto.html#verify-5) should be used. It is part of the new API which does not want any "mpint" values (binaries with size tags).

Comment: Sorry. How to get Mpint from base64KeyString?

Comment: @aposto I updated my answer. Sorry but I don't know about base64 key strings.

Comment: I am inspired by your answer got RSA Exponent & Modulus through openssl.   '"openssl rsa -pubin -inform PEM -text -noout < appexam.pub"'

Answer (score 0):

```
valid_purchase(Receipt, Signature, PublicKey) ->
    PublicKeyBytes = base64:decode(PublicKey),
    SignatureBytes = base64:decode(Signature),
    {'SubjectPublicKeyInfo', _, KeyDer} = public_key:der_decode('SubjectPublicKeyInfo', PublicKeyBytes),
    PublicKey2 = public_key:der_decode('RSAPublicKey', KeyDer),
    public_key:verify(Receipt, sha, SignatureBytes, PublicKey2).
```